# jQuery App locks IE8 up Entirely | Works in everything else just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a ajax/jquery quiz for my company and it runs without problem in Firefox, Chrome, and even Android. When running with IE8, though, it locks up to the effect of having to run the task manager to end the IE process. I have tried different browsers in different operating systems, and the only one that's giving me any trouble is specifically IE in Windows. Other browsers in Windows aren't having any problems. I have also tried on a few different computers.

The Ajax request itself is fine; I think it's the hide/show effects that are causing the issue, after a user chooses an answer. The other answers are supposed to go away, and some response text based on the user's answer appears. Pretty standard. In IE the response text appears, but the other answers don't go away, and then IE locks hard.

I tried using Firebug Lite, but there's no way to actually get any feedback from it since IE freezes to such a great extent.

The javascript is below, and the link to the live example [IS HERE](http://www.turnleftllc.com/cpccs/kymQuiz/).

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        var score=0;

                        $('#getStarted').click(function() {
                                $('#instructions').hide('slow');
                                $('#getStarted').hide('fast');
                                $.ajax({
                                        url: "scripts/quizProgress.php",
                                        data: "questionNumber=1",
                                        success: function(xml) {
                                                        var question = $(xml).find("text:[type=question]").text();
                                                        $('#questionDisplay').append(question);
                                                        $('#questionDisplay').show('slow');
                                                        $(xml).find("answer").each(function() {
                                                                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                                                                var answerText = $(this).find("text").text();
                                                                var tbi = "<p correct='";
                                                                if ($(this).find("correct").text() == '0') {
                                                                        tbi += "no";
                                                                }
                                                                else { tbi += "yes"; }
                                                                tbi += "' id='" + id + "'>" + answerText + "</p>";
                                                                $('#answerDisplay').append(tbi);
                                                                var responseText = $(this).find('response').text();
                                                                var responseInsert = "<p id='re"+id+"' class='hideResponse'>"+responseText+"</p>";
                                                                $('#responseDisplay').append(responseInsert);

                                                        });
                                                        $('#answerDisplay').show('slow');
                                                }


                                });
                        });

     $('#answerDisplay').hover(function() {
                                $(this).find('p').hover(function() {
                                        $(this).addClass("answerHover");
                                        }, function() {
                                        $(this).removeClass('answerHover');
                                });
                                $(this).find('p').click(function() {
                                        if ($(this).attr('correct')=='yes') {
                                        score ++;
                                        }
                                        var answer = $(this).attr('id');
                                        var allAnswers = $('#answerDisplay').find('p');
                                        $(allAnswers).each(function() {
                                                if (answer != $(this).attr('id')) {
                                                        $(this).hide('slow');
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                        $(this).addClass('selectedAnswer');
                                                }
                                        var responseID = "re"+answer;
                                        $('#responseDisplay').find('p').each(function() {
                                                if ($(this).attr('id')==responseID) {
                                                        $(this).removeClass('hideResponse');
                                                        $(this).show('slow');
                                                        $(this).addClass('showResponse');
                                                }
                                        });

                                        });
                                });
                        });

                });
```

Bear in mind, this is only one question, and does not have full funciontality yet. I'm hesitant to continue while it's causing this much of an issue in IE. A lot of our clients  are...let's just say not the computer savvy demographic, and IE comprises a lot of their browsers.

Also: this is my first jQuery application, so it may be that I've done something absolutely horrible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it freeze entirely, or is it just hanging because the script is still running? IE's javascript engine (prior to IE9) isn't very fast, and it's likely that IE is choking because it's taking a long time to run the script.

Comment: You can't minimize, close, or see any cursor effects in IE (like, hovering over the "home" button doesn't highlight it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be to do with:

$(this).hide("slow");

Your triggering a separate animation for each of your non-selected answers.

I'm not certain, but maybe if you triggered a single .hide() for all of the things you wanted to hide, then it may run faster.

Perhaps you could re-factor your code so that it marks the selected answer first and hides everything else.

Maybe, replace this:

```
var answer = $(this).attr('id');
var allAnswers = $('#answerDisplay').find('p');
$(allAnswers).each(function() {
    if (answer != $(this).attr('id')) {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selectedAnswer');
    }
```

with this:

```
$(this).addClass('selectedAnswer');
$('#answerDisplay').find('p').not('.selectedAnswer').hide('slow');
```

But to be honest I don't know exactly how the animate works internally, so I'm not entirely sure if this will be faster.

Comment: @Tom Thorogood: Cool; I'd be interested to see if it helps, let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Sadly, no. The same thing happens. :-/  (/indexTest.php)

Comment: Okay. I removed the 'slow' parameter and it works fine. So the animation is definitely what's causing it. I'm happy to work without it for now, though I like the prettiness. Thanks for the cleaner code, though!

Comment: @Tom Thorogood - oh well worth a shot :-) Perhaps instead of animating you could do an ol' .css("display", "none");  . Or maybe hiding an entire div containing the answers and copying the selected answer outside of the div.

Answer (score 2):

I've cleaned up your code a little bit and changed the showing and hiding of the questions and answers. Hope this is of use to you.

```
var score = 0;
var $answerDisplay = $('#answerDisplay');
var $responseDisplay = $('#responseDisplay');
var $questionDisplay = $('#questionDisplay');
var $instructions = $('#instructions');

$('#getStarted').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide('fast');

    $instructions.hide('slow');

    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/quizProgress.php",
        data: "questionNumber=1",
        success: function(xml) {
            var question = $(xml).find("text:[type=question]").text();
            $questionDisplay.append(question);
            $questionDisplay.show('slow');

            $(xml).find("answer").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var id = $this.attr('id');
                var answerText = $this.find("text").text();
                var tbi = "<p correct='";

                if ($this.find("correct").text() == '0') {
                    tbi += "no";
                } else {
                    tbi += "yes";
                }

                tbi += "' id='" + id + "'>" + answerText + "</p>";

                $answerDisplay.append(tbi);

                var responseText = $this.find('response').text();
                var responseInsert = "<p id='re" + id + "' class='hideResponse'>" + responseText + "</p>";

                $responseDisplay.append(responseInsert);
            });

            $answerDisplay.show('slow');
        }
    });
});

$answerDisplay.find('p').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("answerHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('answerHover');
}).click(function() {
    var $p = $(this);

    $p.addClass('selectedAnswer');

    if ($p.attr('correct') == 'yes') {
        score++;
    }

    $p.parent().find(':not(.selectedAnswer)').hide('slow');
    $responseDisplay.find('p#re' + $p.attr('id')).removeClass('hideResponse').show('slow').addClass('showResponse');
});
```

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry  I didn't see this earlier! Thank you! I'll look over this and put what I haven't already re-written into practice.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but I also added "window.browser = navigator.appName" to the top of the jQuery, and then added the following two functions to replace the calls for hide/show throughout the script - condensed for charspace in the comment:function effectIn(obj) {if (window.browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {$(obj).show();} else {$(obj).show('slow');}}

    function effectOut(obj) {if (window.browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {$(obj).hide();}else {$(obj). hide('slow');} }   These can then be called so specialFX are only in non IE: effectIn('#eleName');